# unable to send html output in mailbody using php mailer library

Tags: php, html, email

i am sending a mail using php mailer library.i want to send html output in mail body. Mail is successfully send but output is not showing properly. full html code is showing. Below is my code. Can anybody help me please.

```
require_once('../../OSTboard/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('../../OSTboard/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('../../OSTboard/PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');

$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->SMTPDebug = 0; 
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';


$email->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$email->Port = 465;
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username = "bosu_cse2k5";
$email->Password = "***********";

$output = '<html><body><form>';
$output .=  '<table border="1"><tr><th>Author</th><th>Node Title</th><th>Node Summary</th><th>Node Body</th><th>Edit this node</th><th>Report Abuse</th><th>Group</th></tr>';
$output .= '</table></form></body></html>';
//print $output;


$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$email->From      = 'bosu_cse2k5@yahoo.com';

$email->FromName  = 'Basudev';
$email->Subject   = 'test';
$email->Body      = $output;
$email->AddAddress( 'basudev.sadhu@bkash.com' );

if(!$email->Send())
{
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $email->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
'Mail send successfully';   

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to set your headers to `$email` anywhere?

Comment: Can you please let me know where i have to set header??

Comment: It looks like you might non need `$headers` at all. Try adding `$email->IsHTML(true);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set

```
$email->IsHTML(true);
```

for more detail visit https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Add "echo" to the else part of "if(!$email->Send())".

Comment: My concern was not that.......i want to send the output of html code....mail is successfully sending.. but in body it is showing full html code. not the output of html code.

Comment: use $email->IsHTML(true);